# Are "the meaning of life", art, and in particular "the life of an artist" themes in Chekhov's drama "The Seagull"?

Tags: russian-language, anton-chekhov, theme, the-seagull

Are "the meaning of life", art, and in particular "the life of an artist" themes in Chekhov's drama "The Seagull"?